# Is JavaEE6 (embedded)container implementations available for experiments?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, embedded-container

Is javaee6/ejb3.1 implementation available from openejb?
Is javaee6/jpa2.0 implementation available from openjpa?

I am trying to evaluate javaee6 and ejb3.1 and jpa2.0 with maven as a build tool; so trying to find the maven artifacts for it. Please suggest Any opensource javaee6 embedded container full implementation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ejb3.1 implementation is not yet ready from openejb.
jpa2.0 implementation is ready from openjpa.

Answer (score 1):

Current state of OpenEJB 3.2-SNAPSHOT is in pretty good condition wrt EJB 3.1

For those interested, keep an eye on this page:

https://cwiki.apache.org/OPENEJB/ejb-31-roadmap.html

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to evaluate javaee6 and ejb3.1 and jpa2.0 with maven as a build tool; so trying to find the maven artifacts for it. Please suggest Any opensource javaee6 embedded container full implementation.

There is obviously GlassFish and the [Embedded GlassFish](http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/). Here is the relevant artifact:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>download.java.net</id>
    <name>Java.net Maven Repository</name>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
...

<dependencies>  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
```

Actually, providing an embeddable container API is part of the Java EE 6 specification (Chapter 22 of the [EJB 3.1](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr318/index.html) spec). See [`EJBContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/embeddable/EJBContainer.html).

#### See also

- [Embedding EJB 3.1 Container Into Your Unit Tests - Boot Time: 5 Seconds](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/embedding_ejb_3_1_container)
- [TOTD #128: EJBContainer.createEJBContainer: Embedded EJB using GlassFish v3](http://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/totd_128_ejbcontainer_createejbcontainer_embedded)
- [Sun GlassFishTM Enterprise Server v3 Embedded Server Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/821-1208/index.html)
- [Embedding Glassfish V3 in Unit Test - Two Jars, Three Lines Of Code And Five Seconds Start With Deployment](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/embedding_glassfish_v3_in_unit)